# Javascript anonymous function use-case

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am working my way through Eloquent Javascript and I came across a code snippet that looks like this:

```
function greaterThan(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return y > x;
  };
}

var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(10);
show(greaterThanTen(9));
```

Is there any real use-case to defining the function like this with an anonymous function inside of it? Wouldn't it be much simpler to do this:

```
function greaterThan(x,y){
  return x > y;
}

var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(9, 10);
```

any ideas/comments/suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Those two options do two diffent things...

Comment: @gdoron To me it appears they do the same thing in a different manner.

Comment: They do different things probably due to a typo. The initial eventually returns y > x, the secondary returns x > y.

Comment: @BrendonDugan Try running both examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is an example of a "closure"](http://jsfiddle.net/HpWxn/). Basically, a call to `greaterThan()` gives you a function. That function, instead of just a mere function, carries with it the value of `x` - it's like embedding the value of `x` permanently into the function.

```
function obj(x) {

    //"public interface"
    //only these are exposed (inc and getX). x is private.
    return {
        inc: function() {
            return ++x;
        },
        getX: function() { //a getter function to retrieve private x
            return x;
        }
    }
}

//the value 10 is "embedded" to the returned object
var myobj = obj(10);

//every call to inc increments that "embedded" value
console.log(myobj.inc()); //11
console.log(myobj.inc()); //12
console.log(myobj.inc()); //13

//but you can never access the variable of `x` directly without a "getter"
console.log(myobj.getX());​
```

Closures are one of the great features of JavaScript. One of it's great uses is to emulate private variables.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you are combining functions.

Of course you can write in different ways but the idea of greaterThanTen in the first example is be something different. For example you can pass this to a filter

```
var a = [ 1 , 10, 100 , 9, 43 ];

function greaterThan(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return y > x;
  };
}
var greaterThanTen = greaterThan(10);
a.filter(greaterThanTen);
```

returns [100, 43]

It is functional programming. There is many advantages.

Comment: Ah I see, so using filter it would apply the inner function to every element in the array.

Comment: and you dont have mudable state. you cant change the greaterThanTen to work as greaterThanOne

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, the first code returns a function.
The second one returns the result.

Comment: That's kind of what I am getting at; I don't know why you would ever return a function when you can just compute the result, returning the function seems like overhead.

Comment: I typed a huge comment, then realised the other 2 answers on this page aleady covered it!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a particularly good use case. A better use case for anonymous functions is callbacks, as in: you wish to execute function #2 once function #1 is completed.

```
function a(param1, param2, callback) {
    //work on param1 and param2 here
    callback.call(); //triggers the callback function
}
```